# Overriding a method from a gem with a condition in Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am using the gritter gem for displaying simple notifications in my rails app. In my controllers I use the gflash method which later adds a notification in a view like so:

```
gflash notification: "Welcome to my awesome website!"
```

Now the problem is that I am making completely different views for mobile, and I need to override [this method which is located in the Gflash module](https://github.com/RobinBrouwer/gritter/blob/master/lib/gritter/gflash.rb). What I want is something that looks like this:

```
If the browser is a mobile browser
  Do this
else
  Use the original gflash method in Gritter::Gflash
end
```

So I added an initializer in config/initializers/custom_gritter.rb:

```
Gritter::Gflash.module_eval do
    def gflash *args
            @@mobile_notifications == [] ? @@mobile_notifications.push(args[0][:notice]) : @@mobile_notifications = [args[0][:notice]]
    end

    def self.mobile_notifications
        @@mobile_notifications ||= []
    end

    def self.reset_mobile_notifications
        @@mobile_notifications = nil
    end
end
```

This allows me to have access to the user notifications in my controllers or views and it works fine:

```
Gritter::Gflash.mobile_notifications
```

But I still have to make sure it overrides only if the user has a mobile device so I changed the custom_gritter.rb file to:

```
Gritter::Gflash.module_eval do
    alias_method :original_gflash, :gflash
    def gflash *args
        puts "override works"
        if browser.mobile?
            puts "detected mobile browser"
            @@mobile_notifications == [] ? @@mobile_notifications.push(args[0][:notice]) : @@mobile_notifications = [args[0][:notice]]
        else
            original_gflash
        end
    end

    def self.mobile_notifications
        @@mobile_notifications ||= []
    end

    def self.reset_mobile_notifications
        @@mobile_notifications = nil
    end
end
```

In my terminal I see "override works" but I don't see "detected mobile browser" which means that the condition doesn't work. the `browser.mobile?` method is provided by the [browser gem](https://github.com/fnando/browser). I also used the is_mobile_request? method from [the mobylette gem](https://github.com/tscolari/mobylette) but I have the exact same issue.

Why isn't it working? Does the module have access to the methods in the other gems? Is this a bad approach to solve my problem ? Any suggestion/idea would be greatly appreciated, thanks in advance !

**update:** I don't have an error which means that it considers `browser.mobile?` to be false even when I'm opening my browser on a mobile( with chrome). I could confirm this by adding `puts "not mobile browser"` after the else statement, which appeared in my terminal.

Any idea why `browser.mobile?` returns true in a controller and false in this module?

Comment: i don't really have the time to provide a full answer or to make sure it's really  what you want, but since you still have no answer: You should look into Ruby's `super` method to invoke original method

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I know how `super` works, but it didn't work and alias_method helped me fix that. The main issue however is with the `if browser.mobile?` line, I have updated my question, can you please take a look? Please don't hesitate to leave a comment again anything you say can guide me to the right direction :)